# What's the difference between "lesson" and "program"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I'm looking at a tennis coaching website and they have tennis lessons and programs for adults and children. What's the difference between them?

Comment: A lesson is one lesson, a program is a series of lessons.

Comment: ...or indeed a [***program of lessons.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=program+of+lessons&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) In such contexts, a "program" ***is*** a series (of lessons, concerts, events, etc.).

Comment: (And of course the latter would be ‘programme’ in the UK, NZ, and India, since this isn't about computer software.)

Answer (score 2):

lesson is generally a single session, and would focus on a single topic (for tennis perhaps strengthening the back-hand return). A program would either focus on more than one topic or cover multiple sessions all aimed at a particular topic.

Answer (score 1):

The word "lesson" means a session of instruction or a class. The word "program" is much more general. The most relevant definition here would be "a set of events" or "a course of study".

As to what the difference is in this context ... you'd have to ask the tennis school. I see another poster said that a "lesson" is a single session on one topic while a "program" is multiple sessions. I can only say, well, maybe that's what they meant. And maybe not. One could readily say, "We offer a series of lessons on all aspects of tennis. We also have a single-session program for beginners."